# How to write into a single file through multiple classes in Java?

Tags: java, io, writefile

I am trying to write into a single text file through different classes.
I opened the text file from the main class:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/t1.txt"));
    Parser.getParseTree().print(); // where I called the method
    writer.close();
  }
```

This is a print() method from another class:

```
    public static  void print() throws IOException {

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/t1.txt"));
            writer.write("afcad fad fad");
     }
```

The `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/t1.txt"));`in print() method does not work and nothing prints into the **t1.txt**
 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have multiple places (methods) that each write to the file on their own.

Simply use one central place that opens the file for writing (probably using try-with-resource) and have any other code call a method at that central place. In other words, all your code should just invoke the same method!